# cv.glmnet: printed lambda.min and lambda.1se differ from their stored values

Tags: r, glmnet

```
set.seed(0)
a <- runif(100)
b <- runif(100)
c <- runif(100)
d <- b + runif(100)/10
e <- a + runif(100)/10

library(glmnet)
test <- cv.glmnet(cbind(a,b,c), cbind(d,e), family = "mgaussian",
                  relax = TRUE, gamma = 0.5)
```

In this example, printing `test` directly gives something like:

```
test
#Measure: Mean-Squared Error 
#
#    Gamma Index   Lambda Index  Measure        SE Nonzero
#min   0.5     1 0.001617    56 0.001872 0.0001121       4
#1se   0.5     1 0.015082    32 0.001967 0.0001393       3
```

It appears that `lambda.min` should be 0.001617. However, I get a different number when I extract this value:

```
test$lambda.min
#[1] 0.0007682971
```

Anyone know why there is a difference? I'm using **glmnet** 4.1-4. My **R** version is:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `relax = TRUE` in `cv.glmnet`, two sets of cross-validation are performed:

1. the usual one for the `relax = FALSE` case;
2. the special one for the `relax = TRUE` case.

Their results are stored in different places, and there are two methods for `print`.

Result for `relax = FALSE`:

```
print.cv.glmnet(test)

test$lambda.min
```

Result for `relax = TRUE` (stored in `test$relaxed`):

```
test
#print(test)
#glmnet:::print.cv.relaxed(test)

test$relaxed$lambda.min
```

---

> Thank you. This is the correct answer. Could you clarify why the `relax = FALSE` and `relax = TRUE` models are different, given that I only supplied one value for `gamma`? Are the default `gamma` values `c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)` always used when `relax = FALSE`?

If `relax = FALSE`, whatever you supply for `gamma` will be ignored and there is no `test$relaxed`.

When `relaxed = TRUE`, any `gamma` value in [0, 1) causes "relaxation", whereas `gamma = 1` reverts to the `relax = FALSE` case. If you provide more than one `gamma` values, the 2nd set of cross-validation will also select `gamma` (see `gamma.min` and `gamma.1se` in `test$relaxed`).